# Image denoising for OCR (Optical character recognisation)

Tags: android, opencv, image-processing, client-server, ocr

I am developing one application in Android.
i am confuse at one place where i want to denoise the image before processing it for OCR
so my question is where should i keep this functionality of denoising of image
At server side/ at client side.And what are the advantage of choosing at server/client side

Answer (score 0):

As many other preprocessing steps, denoising the source image can be crucial to achieve good recognition results. Of course, the relevance of performing noise reduction will depend on the environmental factors affecting to the quality of the image, but in most cases it can do with a noise reduction step!

Regarding the client/server processing, I usually tend to keep in the client side all the image processing steps which can help reducing the size of the image to be sent towards the server (basically operations like "RGB->gray", image resizing and region of interest selection). I'd include image denoising as part of the server side processing workload. But, of course, it depends on what type of "client" machine are you going to use.

Comment: am using Android platform or mobile technology at client side

Comment: In that case I recommend you to move the image processing tasks towards the server as much as possible, with the exception of the above mentioned operations.